# Action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$ giving a non-trivial homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

> If $H < A_5$ is a subgroup of index $3$, the action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$ gives a non-trivial homomorphism
>   $$\underset{order \ 60}G \rightarrow \underset{order \ 6}{S_3}$$ 
>   which must have a kernel $$\{e\} \triangleleft_\neq N \triangleleft_\neq G$$
>   But G is simple so this is impossible.

I asumme that the action of $G$ is just a permutation on three elements hence $S_3$ but I cannot see how this will definitely be a non-trivial homomorphism. Nor can I see why this must have a non-trivial kernel

Does this method work in general or will there be cases where it doesnt work.

Comment: This is a standard construction for any subgroup $H$ of any group $G$. If $H \ne G$, then there exists $g \in G$ with $gH \ne H$, so the image is non-trivial. It really is clear that the kernel must be non-trivial - think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general thing one can do is the following: Let $H\leq G$ and define an action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ by $g.(kH) = (gk)H$ (so $g$ sends the coset containing $k$ to the coset containing $gk$).

It is easy to check that this is indeed an action of $G$, so it defines an homomorphism to $S_m$ where $m$ is the index of $H$ in $G$.

To see that this is a non-trivial action (when $H\neq G$), note that if $g\not\in H$ then $g.(eH) = gH \neq H$ so $g$ does not act as the identity on the coset $H$.

Comment: What is the conclusion of this?

Comment: @sandstone That whenever $H\neq G$ the action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ is nontrivial.

Comment: and so....? Sorry if I am being slow but I just cannot see the consequence of this

Comment: @sandstone What do you mean the consequence? The question was whether the action was always nontrivial.

Comment: but if the action is non trivial and this is impossible what does this mean?

Comment: @sandstone In the concrete case that there is no subgroup of index $3$.

Comment: Thats what I cant see

Comment: @sandstone The assumption that there is a subgroup of index $3$ leads to there being a proper nontrivial normal subgroup which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel is trivial, the map is injective, which cannot happen.  If the homomorphism itself is trivial, then $H$ is normal, which also cannot happen.

Comment: Is it not injective because $6<60$? I dont understand your second sentence

Comment: @sandstone Yes, there is no injective function from a set with $60$ elements to a set with $6$ elements.  For the second sentence, what happens if $H$ is _not_ normal?  Then $g^{-1}Hg \neq H$ for some $g$.  Can such a $g$ be sent to the identity permutation under the map $A_5 \to S_3$?

Comment: I still dont understand the second sentence nor the conclusion made by taking the two sentences together

Comment: @sandstone Explain what you don't understand about my previous comment.  And remember, we are trying to find a contradiction.  We do this using the simplicity of $G$—because kernels are normal subgroups, there are only two possibilities for the kernel of $G\to S_3$, and we want to demonstrate that both are impossible.